# Python discord bot on heroku crashing because of FileNotFoundError. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to host a bot from github on heroku, but it won't go online. I get a FileNotFoundError, and it says the "Process exited with status 1."

```
2021-10-13T21:19:08.546118+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-10-13T21:19:11.213260+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python main.py`
2021-10-13T21:19:12.065471+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-10-13T21:19:12.403989+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-10-13T21:19:12.404003+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
2021-10-13T21:19:12.404070+00:00 app[worker.1]: logger.init(debug, quiet)
2021-10-13T21:19:12.404071+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/utils/logger.py", line 30, in init
2021-10-13T21:19:12.404137+00:00 app[worker.1]: log_file = logging.FileHandler('logs/bot.log', mode='w', encoding="UTF-8")
2021-10-13T21:19:12.404138+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1087, in __init__
2021-10-13T21:19:12.404441+00:00 app[worker.1]: StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
2021-10-13T21:19:12.404450+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1116, in _open
2021-10-13T21:19:12.404733+00:00 app[worker.1]: return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
2021-10-13T21:19:12.404757+00:00 app[worker.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/logs/bot.log'
2021-10-13T21:19:12.555329+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-10-13T21:19:14.167674+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Comment: `No such file or directory: '/app/logs/bot.log'`—okay, well, what are you trying to do with `logs/bot.log`? On Heroku you generally want to configure your logs to stream to `stdout` or `stderr`.

Comment: @Chris It's not my code so I don't know. Also, I have basically no coding knowledge. How do I configure it to do that?

Comment: I have no way of knowing without seeing your code. This is a Q&A site for _programming_ questions. "I have basically no coding knowledge"—you need to at least be willing to read your code and show us the relevant parts if you want to get help here. If you can't to that, I'm afraid you're in the wrong place. I suggest you ask whoever wrote the code for help.